generating a polynomial algorithm from the given one-way function
I am trying to solve the following problem:
Suppose that $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} $ is a one-way function
and that for some function $l: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, the following conditions hold:
(a) $|f(x)|=l(|x|)$ for all $x$'s;
(b) $l(n)=l(m)$ only if $n=m$ (i.e., $l$ is $1-1$);
(c) $l(n) \geq n$ for all $n$'s.
Prove that given $f(x)$, one can generate $1^{|x|}$ ( $1$ written $|x|$ times, where $|x|$ is the length of $x$ e.g. $|12345678| = 8$), in time polynomial in $|x|$.
Any hint will be appreciated.
P.S. I have access to the solution but I am unable to understand it completely.

Say we are given $f(x_0)$ for some $x_0 \in \mathbb{N}$. Note that combining (a) and (c), we have that $|f(x)| = l(|x|) \ge |x| $, therefore, $|x_0| \le |f(x_0)|$. We can use this fact to test for possible values of $|x_0|$ by evaluating $l(0), l(1), l(2), \dots,$ until we find that $l(n) = |f(x_0)|$, and we conclude that $|x_0| = n$, because $l$ is injective. With the knowledge of $|x_0|$ we can compute $1^{|x_0|}$. This works in polynomial time assuming we can evaluate both $f$ and $l$ in polynomial time, because $n$ is bounded by $|f(x_0)|$.

You are given $b$ and want to find $a$ such that $l(a)=b$.  Just iterate over all possible values of $a$, for $a=1,2,3,\dots$, until you find a solution.
